# call onClick in laytout method from viewholder

Tags: android

I am getting the below error :

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find method onClick(View) in a parent or ancestor Context for android:onClick attribute defined on view class android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton
```

I am calling the onClick below:

```
private class MyViewHolderHeader extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        private final RecyclerView mHeaderRecyclerView;
        public void  onClick(View v)
        {
            Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, XActivity.class);
            mContext.startActivity(intent);
        }
        public MyViewHolderHeader(View v) {
            super(v);

            mHeaderRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) v.findViewById(R.id.recycler_view_horizontal);
            HeaderItemsAdapter mAdapter = new HeaderItemsAdapter(getItemHeader(),mContext);
            LinearLayoutManager layoutManager
                    = new LinearLayoutManager(mContext, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false);

            mHeaderRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
            mHeaderRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
        }
    }
```

I have the below viewHolder ,

In the onCreateViewHolder

```
    View v =  LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.main_item_header, parent, false);

    return new MyViewHolderHeader(v);
```

Edit

```
   private final View.OnClickListener mOnClickListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(final View view) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, Ps4ItemsActivity.class);
            mContext.startActivity(intent);
        }
    };


public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    if (viewType == TYPE_ITEM) {
        //inflate your layout and pass it to view holder
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.main_item_adapter, parent, false);

        MainItemsViewholder vh = new MainItemsViewholder(v, new MainItemsViewholder.IMyViewHolderClicks() {
            public void onPotato(View caller) { Log.d("VEGETABLES", "Poh-tah-tos");
                Intent intent = new Intent(mContext,SingleItemActivity.class);
                mContext.startActivity(intent);
            };
            public void onTomato(ImageView callerImage) {
                Log.d("VEGETABLES", "To-m8-tohs");


                Intent intent = new Intent(mContext,Ps4ItemsActivity.class);
                mContext.startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
        return new MyViewHolder(v);
    } else if (viewType == TYPE_HEADER) {
        //inflate your layout and pass it to view holder
        View v =  LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.main_item_header, parent, false);
        v.setOnClickListener(mOnClickListener);

        return new MyViewHolderHeader(v);
    }
    throw new RuntimeException("there is no type that matches the type " + viewType + " + make sure your using types correctly");

}
```

Comment: is it compile error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to assign a listener to your view, for example you can create an onclickListener :

```
private final View.OnClickListener mOnClickListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(final View view) {
      .....
       .....
    }
};
```

and assing it to your view into the `onCreateViewHolder()` method:

```
@Override
public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(final ViewGroup parent, final int viewType) {
     View v =  LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.main_item_header, parent, false);
    view.setOnClickListener(mOnClickListener);
    return new MyViewHolderHeader(view);
}
```

Comment: I have added the listener with the implementation of onClick() method.

Comment: i am still getting this error  Could not find method onClick(View) in a parent or ancestor Context  .. please check my update question with full code and how i add your code

Answer (score -1):

Your hint is in the error.

> `in a parent or ancestor Context`

A ViewHolder is not a `Context`.

You need to define that method on the Activity.

---

If you want the method in the ViewHolder or Adapter, you cannot use `android:onClick` in the XML

Comment: but I have the onClick in viewholder which it insider an adapter , so how to call onClick method when user click on the button ? did you understand me?

Comment: I don't think you understood me. The adapter isn't a Context either. An Activity is.